# How to enable year Before/After Specific year in Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing only year in calender view using datepicker.

But I want to set maximum year range to current year and minimum year range to 1900 and disable year before/after range I want to set in Datepicker like the below image.

[image]
[image]

Here is my javascript code:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        format: "yyyy",
        viewMode: "years",
        minViewMode: "years",
        autoclose: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1900:' + new Date().getFullYear()
    });
```

But year range is not working for me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to limit the range of dates the user can pick? or the range of years in the datepicker itself?

Comment: I want to limit the range of year. You can see the above image, I edited my question.

Comment: did you manage to fix the problem?

Comment: No I am still facing the problem.

Comment: I've added another method

Answer (score 0):

**edit - different approach**

---

try using the minDate and maxDate attributes:

```
let cur_year = (new Date).getFullYear();
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(1900, 0, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(cur_year, 11, 31)
});
```

---

you should convert the date back to string after you get the current year,
currently, you are trying to add a date to a string (that's not possible)

so it should look something like that:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        format: "yyyy",
        viewMode: "years",
        minViewMode: "years",
        autoclose: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1900:' + new Date().getFullYear().toString()
    });
```

Comment: It didnot work for me.

Comment: can you elaborate on what still not working?

Comment: I want to disable after/before specific year, In my case i want to set min year 1900 and maximum year to current year.

Comment: This also doesnot work for me. I edited my question, added two image for reference. I want exact like that.